# C# - Dns.GetHostEntry(uri.Host) in .net core?

Tags: c#, dns, .net-core

I can take IP address of uri like "google.com" with Dns.GetHostEntry("google.com"), for example:

```
        var ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("google.com");
        Console.WriteLine(ip.AddressList.FirstOrDefault().ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

This code works fine in .net framework but I have a cross platform project and need to use this code in .net core 1.1 and .net standard 1.6 but .net core and standard version is not support System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry,
How can I take Server Ip Address from host name with Dns in .net core and standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After check again I found Dns.GetHostEntryAsync in .net standard and .net core,I change my code to this for support .net4 and .net45 and .net core and .net standard:

```
#if (NETSTANDARD1_6 || NETCOREAPP1_1)
            IPHostEntry Host = await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(uri.Host);
#else
            IPHostEntry Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(uri.Host);
#endif
```

Comment: why `NETSTANDARD1_6 || NETCOREAPP1_1`? and not just `NETSTANDARD1_6`?
If this is a library, you only have to target netstandard, not netcoreapp (or I'm interested in knowing why)

Comment: Because if I use  Microsoft.NETCore.CoreCLR package in the future in my project .net standdard is not support that library, and i use both of .net core and .net standard in my project,that is just for latter